# Two Bluetooth Keyboards - 2 Different Sets of Home & End buttons Actions on Windows via Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, remote-desktop, bluetooth, macos-ventura

I use Microsoft Remote Desktop on my MacBook Pro (Ventura 13.5) to access my office desktop (Windows 10 Pro Education 22H2) via our VPN.

If I use Apple's Magic Keyboard the Home and End keys on the keyboard function as expected - moving the cursor to the start or end of the current line in Windows.

However, if I use the Rii Wireless Keyboard (Rii RK801 Wireless Bluetooth Keyboard) with the laptop and press the Home or End keys it docks the window I am working on to the left (home) or right (end) of the screen and shows me other windows which can be tiled on the other half of the screen.

So the question is how can I change this behavior with the Rii keyboard to have it move the cursor to the start or end of the line instead of having the windows resize on the remote Windows PC?

Any guidance you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

---

@Tetsujin mentioned checking both keyboards using the Mac App KeyCodes, which I did
[Screen Shot - Comparing Key Code output for both keyboards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX4ZY.png)

| Key Pressed | Apple MagicKeyboard | Rii RK801 Wireless BT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [HOME] | Unicode: 63273 / 0xf729 Keys: ⬉ Keycode: 115 / 0x73 | Unicode: 63234 / 0xf702 Keys: ⌘← Keycode: 123 / 0x7b |
| [END] | Unicode: 63275 / 0xf72b Keys: ➘ Keycode: 119 / 0x77 | Unicode: 63235 / 0xf703 Keys: ⌘→ Keycode: 124 / 0x7c |

Is there a way to "remap" the Rii Keyboard to actually do what the Apple MagicKeyboard sends?

Comment: Get hold of [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) (freeware) from the app store & check both keyboards are actually sending the same output.

Comment: @Tetsujin that is for the Mac is there a version for Windows? Since it is Windows that is having the issue (apparently). I will test it on the mac as well.

Comment: No, it's the keyboard you're having trouble with, not Windows or RDC. The Rii is sending the wrong keys entirely. See if pressing Fn/← or  → will send the correct codes [that's what a regular Mac keyboard should do]

Comment: Does the mapping need to happen on the Mac side of things, or the Win? If Win, I've used SharpKeys to remap keys in Windows (https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys/releases)

Comment: @music2myear - on the Mac side really, unless that remapper is switchable or can be set to be keyboard specific [though of course it cannot know which keyboard is being used:\ Windows is only responding to what the Mac is actually sending. In Text areas Cmd/← is 'beginning of line' rather than Home. Outside of text areas it has no defined function, whereas Home still does. Windows would likely re-interpret Cmd/← as  Win⊞/←

Comment: I am actually looking at Karabiner-Elements to see if that tool can do what I am looking for. Will have to try this afternoon. This section from their help section (https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/manual/configuration/configure-devices/) seems like a possibility.

Comment: @psycoperl - it's something I'm familiar with - but only as a recommendation for awkward key remapping - it's not something I've ever actually used myself. Wish you luck. If you struggle with it, there are experts here & on https://apple.stackexchange.com/ who could probably help out.

Comment: @Tetsujin - thank you I have posted the followup question on the apple.stackexchange as recommended: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/462522/using-karabiner-to-modify-keyboard-keys